# scoverage-maven-plugin error with scala 2.12.13

Tags: scala, maven, scoverage

I have scala mvn project. Version of scala was 2.12.3 and scoverage-maven-plugin. 1.3.0 After updating scala version from 2.12.3  to 2.12.13 I have got an error

```
[ERROR] error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Global.reporter()Lscala/tools/nsc/reporters/Reporter;
```

By looking at https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/issues/321 and related commits it seems like using scalac-scoverage v1.4.3 would fix it, so I tried to force it to use a different one like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scoverage.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.12.13</scalaVersion>
                <scalacPluginVersion>1.4.3</scalacPluginVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but I've got a new error:

```
Failure to find org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.12:jar:1.4.3 in http://repo.mal.internal/content/groups/public was cached in the local rep
ository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of internal.mirror has elapsed or updates are forced
```

but `scalaVersion` param accept only 2.10 or 2.11 or 2.13. How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the maven repo page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin) for now there is not 1.4.3 version for the `scoverage-maven-plugin`:

[image]

In the mentioned issue they use a different plugin: `scalac-scoverage-plugin`.